# How to handle duplicate elements in RobotFramework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have html page which has duplicate element IDs, LoginAccount. I want to enter account name in the id, but using robot framework I am always getting exception error. Does anyone have idea how to select specific element ID and then input text into the text box ?

Code:

```
<form-group _ngcontent-c10="" autofocus="true" id="LoginAccount" inputtype="text" labelname="Account" _nghost-c11=""><div _ngcontent-c11="" class="form-group row">
  <!---->
  <!----><!---->
    <label _ngcontent-c11="" class="col-12 col-sm-6">Account</label>
     <!----><input _ngcontent-c11="" class="col-12 col-sm-6 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" id="LoginAccount">

  <!---->
</div>
</form-group>
```

Error:

```
InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

Answer (score 0):

xpath locators:

```
for up element: //from-group[@id='LoginAccount']
for inside element: //from-group[@id='LoginAccount']//input[@id="Account"]
```

use `driver.findElementByXpath() function`

more information about xpath locators [here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium)